# Getting name of functions in classes for Implementing Intellisense using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am creating a Intellisense popup for a xaml application. I need names of all methods under a particular class. I am using reflection.

```
 MethodInfo[] methodInfos = 
    Type.GetType(selectedObjcClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But I get the full name of the method including the namespace and the class name. How to get only function name like in c#?

Comment: Have you tried the MethodInfo Name property?

Comment: They do have an annoying habit of hiding this sort of information in [the Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have an array of `MethodInfo` from your code, you can use the [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property to retrieve the method names. For example, using LINQ:

```
var names = methodInfos.Select(mi => mi.Name);
```